# Imparfait au lieu du conditionnel

Tags: conditionnel, imparfait

Peut-être un sujet déjà évoqué. J'ai reçu l'email ci-dessous :

> Bonjour Monsieur,
>
> **Nous voulions voir avec vous s'il était possible de décaler** la kholle
> de vendredi qui était initialement de 19h à 20h, afin de la mettre le
> jeudi à 11h ou 12h. Si ce n'est pas possible pour vous, nous sommes
> également libre le vendredi midi (le même jour que la kholle initiale)
> de 12h à 13h ou bien de 13h à 14h.
>
> Nous vous remercions d'avance et nous vous souhaitons une bonne
> journée.

Pourquoi 'nous voulions voir' et pas 'nous voudrions voir' ?

Comment: Semblable à l'anglais : "We wanted to ask you..." qui ne veut pas dire qu'on l'a voulu auparavant mais qu'on hésite de faire trop directement une requête.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il s'agit d'un imparfait dit d'atténuation ou de politesse. Il est encore moins directif que le conditionnel *nous voudrions voir* qui lui-même l'est bien moins que le serait le présent *nous voulons voir*.

Une étude des imparfaits atténuatifs à lire dans [Langue française, 2004](https://www.cairn.info/revue-langue-francaise-2004-2-page-58.htm#:%7E:text=imparfait%20dit%20%C2%AB%20de%20politesse%20%C2%BB%2C,l%27actualit%C3%A9%20de%20la%20requ%C3%AAte) :

> Le premier – que nous appellerons *imparfait de justification* – sert, sur le plan discursif, à justifier une situation présente, dont le locuteur pense qu’elle pourrait déranger l’interlocuteur (le plus souvent, une intrusion physique ou téléphonique), et dont il présente les causes sous forme d’intentions passées.
> [...]
> Le second, qui sera baptisé *imparfait de déperformativité*, loin de localiser le procès dans un passé accessible à l’interlocuteur, sert tout simplement à « désamorcer » un acte de langage actuel, le plus souvent de type assertif ou interrogatif. Sur le plan syntaxique, il se rencontre quasi exclusivement avec le verbe *vouloir* gouvernant une infinitive en *dire/demander*.

Une variante de cet imparfait est nommée *l'imparfait forain* :

> *Qu’est-ce qu’elle voulait la petite dame ?*

La troisième personne permet aussi d'esquiver le choix entre tutoiement et vouvoiement.

Comment: Merci encore:-)! C'est un usage enseigné à l'école ?

Comment: Je ne crois pas. Ce n'est probablement pas abordé avant les études de lettres.

Comment: Je suis content des mes élèves:-)!

Comment: Ils ne te manquent pas de respect :-)